# How to find (n+1)th argument value if you find nth value as part of string match from $@ in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

We have a Bash script. How to find (n+1)th argument value if you find nth value as part of string match from $@. n is not known.

1. Is there a way to find the position or value of n? I understand that I can find input argument if it matches with the required string I am looking for.
2. How to find the input argument of next ((n+1)th) position if I find the argument from the input list.

Comment: can you not use `shift [n]` ? If not, then can you share an example ?

Comment: Is this an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for "how do I parse command line options like `./myscript -n 4 -s foo`?"

Comment: Yes, appropriate example ./myscript -n 4 -s foo. Suppose my string matches with -s then I should consider foo. @Jetchisel explained very well. I was looking for the last example he mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the arguments.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
n=1
for f; do
  printf '%s %s\n' "$n" "$f"
  ((n++))
done
```

Running that against a bunch of arguments.

```sh
./myscript {a..z}
```

Output

```sh
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
6 f
7 g
8 h
9 i
10 j
11 k
12 l
13 m
14 n
15 o
16 p
17 q
18 r
19 s
20 t
21 u
22 v
23 w
24 x
25 y
26 z
```

If you're interested in just one argument, say the `g`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n=1
for f; do
  [[ $f == g ]]  &&  printf '%s %s\n' "$n" "$f"
  ((n++))
done
```

```sh
./myscript {a..z}
```

Output

```sh
7 g
```

---

To answer the `n+1` argument, put/assign the arguments in an array and loop through the indices,  now let's say you want the next argument after the `g`, note the `n+1` marks the spot and arrays count starting from zero not one, something like.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

args=("$@")

for n in "${!args[@]}"; do
  [[ ${args[n]} == g ]] && echo "${args[n+1]}"
done
```

```
./myscript {a..z}
```

Ouput

```sh
h
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Jetchisel! I was exactly looking for the last example.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers